# Java Stanford NLP: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds after loading second lexicon

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford Natural Language processing toolkit. I've been trying to find spelling errors with `Lexicon`'s `isKnown` method, but it produces quite a few false positives. So I thought I'd load a second lexicon, and check that too. However, that causes a problem.

```
private static LexicalizedParser lp = new LexicalizedParser(Constants.stdLexFile);
private static LexicalizedParser wsjLexParse = new LexicalizedParser(Constants.wsjLexFile);

    static {
        lp.setOptionFlags(Constants.lexOptionFlags);        
        wsjLexParse.setOptionFlags(Constants.lexOptionFlags);       
    }

public ParseTree(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    initialInput = input;
    DocumentPreprocessor process = new DocumentPreprocessor();
    sentences = process.getSentencesFromText(new StringReader(input));

    for (List<? extends HasWord> sent : sentences) {
        if(lp.parse(sent)) { // line 65
            forest.add(lp.getBestParse()); //non determinism?
        }
    }

    partsOfSpeech = pos();
    runAnalysis();
}
```

The following fail trace is produced:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 45547
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.initRulesWithWord(BaseLexicon.java:300)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.isKnown(BaseLexicon.java:160)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.BaseLexicon.ruleIteratorByWord(BaseLexicon.java:212)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.initializeChart(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:1299)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.ExhaustivePCFGParser.parse(ExhaustivePCFGParser.java:388)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parse(LexicalizedParser.java:234)
    at nth.compling.ParseTree.<init>(ParseTree.java:65)
    at nth.compling.ParseTreeTest.constructor(ParseTreeTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.invokeMethod(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runBefores(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

If I comment out this line: (and other references to wsjLexParse)

```
private static LexicalizedParser wsjLexParse = new LexicalizedParser(Constants.wsjLexFile);
```

then everything works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the Stanford library. You should report it to them.

Does the second lexicon work when you load only it (and not the other one)?
Does the same error occur when you load the two lexica in different order?